# When to repeat a paragraph?

Tags: writing-style, paragraphs

I was reading through [this article](http://thetriangle.org/sports/found-in-translation/) recently, and I noticed that the first and seventh paragraphs are identical.

Stylistically speaking, is it common to repeat entire strings of text as shown here? Speaking personally, I find it awkward to be reading the same thing over again.

I'm not seeking a definitive ruling on this, but rather opinions on the prevalence of this particular styling and formatting choice.

Comment: The introductory paragraph is an exerpt. It's very common; just a way of grabbing someone's attention. Stylewise, you might get a good discussion at writers.se. The quick [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) will give you an idea of what kind of question is on topic here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be what we call a "typographical disaster". What looks like the lead paragraph (or *lede paragraph*) is probably supposed to be a [call-out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callout), but there isn't enough to differentiate it from the running text. Ordinarily, a call-out would have different margins, a *significantly* larger font size, a different typeface or style, borders, or a different background colour to let you know that you are reading an excerpt from the article body.